Permission Denied for Open Json file in Docker Container
I met a problem after I run the docker container, it dockerize the streamlit (python) app. It looks the json file cannot load due to permission issue.
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'inference_data/1234_photo_group.json' Traceback: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 541, in _run_script exec(code, module.__dict__) File "/app/app.py", line 128, in <module> gen_photo_group(report1_images, map_image_cap_1, "1234") File "/app/utils.py", line 188, in gen_photo_group with open("inference_data/" + report_id + "_photo_group.json", "w") as outfile:
Here is my docker file:
`FROM python:3.9-slim
EXPOSE 8080
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
COPY ./key.json /secret/key.json
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD streamlit run app.py --server.port=8080 --server.address=0.0.0.0`

Does it mean I need to grant permission in docker file? or other reason cause the permission issue. Thanks.
I tried to change the dockerfile, but it did not work. I need to know how to change the dockerfile to grant the permission or use other method to resolve this issue. Thanks.

How long does that file need to live?  If you're planning to clean it up promptly, would using /tmp work (which is usually world-writable)?  If it needs to outlive the process/container, you probably need to mount some sort of storage on the data directory, and you'll need to address the ownership problem in your container startup options, not the Dockerfile.
